# Running jhipster with Prod profile

Tags: jhipster

I would like to know about the main differences between running a Jhipster app in Dev mode compared to run it in Production mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is, that all your static resources a optimized (e.g. minimizing and combining javascript files). Furthermore the production profiles enables gzip compression and longer caching of assets. Depending on your configuration the production profile may also use a different database.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so no difference of logging policies between those two modes?

Comment: Oh sorry you're right. The log level in the production profile is info while the loglevel in dev (and fast) is debug.

Comment: Thanks, my prod profile doesn't work (I dont know why), nothing appears on my browser. Is there a way to set log level to info programmatically?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at your maven pom. You can change the log level there. You can also add the log level configuration in your yml config.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here https://jhipster.github.io/production/

1. Generating an optimized JavaScript application with Gulp

Will process all your static resources (CSS, JavaScript, HTML, JavaScript, images...) in order to generate an optimized client-side application.

This code will be served when you run the application with the "production" profile.

2. GZipping
   With the "production" profile, JHipster configures a Servlet filter that applies gzip compression on your resources.

By default, this filter will work on most static resources (excluding images, which are already compressed) and on all REST requests.

3. Cache headers
   With the "production" profile, JHipster configures a Servlet filter that puts specific HTTP cache headers on your static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts...) so they are cached by browsers and proxies.